# How do I change my stackexchange login email?

Tags: support, login, email

I had signed up with an account. But i do not have access to that anymore. I need to change the login id of my stackexchange account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

- Recover your password by going to https://superuser.com/users/account-recovery and entering the e-mail address that you used for your old account. You can then re-activate it.
- Write to the team under https://superuser.com/contact to have your two user profiles merged.